# Mimic the black Google menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put the black Google menu on my website. So far I succeeded in making an exact replica of this menu. However there is one thing I can't seem to figure out: If you look at the menu ([LINK)](http://www.google.nl/) you will see the ul has a padding(or margin) from the left. If you then make your browser window smaller or bigger, this padding/margin seems to change. This happens in all browsers. I first thought they are doing something with percentages, but that's not the case.

Can someone please tell me what this padding/margin is based up on?

Comment: They're using elastic CSS... I don't know why, because it doesn't seem to be all that useful there, but that's what they're doing.  Look up CSS media queries.

Comment: @Brad Thanks:) Will look in to it

Comment: you can try less or sass if you want to make it work with older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for are CSS3's @media queries.
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/